# Accessing values from nested dictionary in TCL

Tags: dictionary, tcl

I have the following dictionary in TCL:

```
main_dict {sub_dict1 {key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3} subdict2 {key1 val1}}
```

How can I access the val3 which is inside my sub_dict1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dict get` with multiple keys:

```
% set mydict {main_dict {sub_dict1 {key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3} subdict2 {key1 val1}}}
main_dict {sub_dict1 {key1 val1 key2 val2 key3 val3} subdict2 {key1 val1}}
% dict get $mydict main_dict sub_dict1 key3
val3
```